# Issue with datagrid opening to default width of both monitors

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

How can I achieve the desired effect of opening the main window with a datagrid width of approximately 840, regardless of the number of monitors, and ensure that the datagrid automatically resizes when the user expands the window? Currently, the datagrid width matches the combined width of my monitors. I have tried various methods, such as using auto width, * width, adjusting row and column spans, setting the width on load in the code behind, having the datagrid in the scroll viewer, etc. but none of them have provided the desired behaviour. I need the datagrid to open at the size I set it prior to expanding. I have narrowed the behaviour down to the actual datagrid, but after trying all the things above, am at a loss.

Please provide assistance on how to achieve this desired behavior.

Thank you!

Here is my code.

```
<Window x:Class="Migrations.FlatFileFolderTool.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Migrations.FlatFileFolderTool.ViewModels" 
        xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" MinHeight="1200" MinWidth="900" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
        <Style x:Key="RoundedButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="6" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Width="160" Height="40">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ededed" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsProcessing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border BorderBrush="#f3a06a" BorderThickness="5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

...
            
            <Grid Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="9">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <DataGrid Margin="20,0,20,0"
                          SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
                          SelectionMode="Single"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding FolderPaths}"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Select All" Binding="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.IsSelectAllChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                              Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectAllCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Folder Path" MinWidth="810" Width="*" Binding="{Binding FolderPath}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>

...

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: I tested it out in a blank project with your code. It opens and resizes with the window just fine. Are you doing something in the ViewModel or code-behind that is affecting the width of these controls? Edit: It opens across both my monitors as well, if you adjust the attribute for your MainWindow.xaml `SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight"` to not include width or remove it altogether then it should work closer to how you describe you want

Comment: If I take out the width from the SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" then it does open smaller but still not at the actual setting I've chosen. There is nothing in the view model that I can see that should ipmact this. This is the only thing I have in the code behind

private readonly MainWindowViewModel viewModel;

     public MainWindow() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(() => new FolderBrowser());
            DataContext = viewModel;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was answered by someone that I work with, so I will post it here in case anyone else ever has the same issue.

@bigcrazyal you were correct to remove the width from the size to content, but this was still not opening my window to the correct size. I also needed to set the width in the main window as well (this sets the size of the width when the window is opened but does not impact resizing).

`Title="MainWindow" MinHeight="900" Width="880" MinWidth="880" SizeToContent="Height"`

Then I needed to remove the MinWidth setting in the actual datagrid and it now works a treat!

`<DataGridTextColumn Header="Folder Path" Width="*" Binding="{Binding FolderPath}" IsReadOnly="True" />`